# what is this pistol John Wick and Caine use during their epic duel?

Tags: props, john-wick-chapter-4

[image: Dueling pistols in John Wick 4]

In the latest movie, John Wick 4, John and Caine use these pistols during their epic duel.
What I found interesting is:

- They are loaded from the rear which suggest their barrels are rifled.

But the shots coming from both John and Caine are relatively inaccurate. I am very interested in knowing the specs of these pistols, anyone knows what they are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Internet Movie Firearms Database](https://www.imfdb.org/wiki/John_Wick:_Chapter_4#Thompson_Center_Arms_Encore) reckon it's a Thompson Centre Arms Encore. The rounds they are used with appear to be custom nickel plated or silver cast .45-70 Government cartridges.

<sup>What I know about guns could be written on the back of a postage stamp, so this is just 'as reported'.</sup>

Comment: Yewtewbers agree: - https://youtu.be/56zihdxSKjA?t=336 / as does: https://johnwick.fandom.com/wiki/John_Wick#Weapons / as does a Firearms Auction site: https://www.rockislandauction.com/riac-blog/john-wick-guns - cost a pretty penny

Answer (score 10):

I am the engraver that designed and worked on these pieces for the film. They are indeed the Thompson Center Arms Encore, with custom barrels and wood. You can read all about them on my blog for all the details.  There are also a few intaglio prints still available in my shop, these are actually lifted from the engravings if you're a fan of the work and into collectibles.  I hope you enjoy!

https://www.melissamstudios.com/blog

https://www.melissamstudios.com/shop

Comment: That's the heck of a job! Congratulations.

Comment: congrats and welcome to the site!